# How to connect a dropdown menu with a callback to select a column for sum in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

1. I'm trying to create a Dash app to analyze some data. The DataFrame I'm using as a base has a few columns with numerical values. I'm attempting to create a dropdown menu where I can select one of these columns, and then sum the selected column.

   Here is the code I'm working on. (I'm very new to coding, apologize for any silly mistakes.)

`

```
                ``slider_options = ['Janeiro/2020', 'fereiro/2020', 'Março/2020',
                    'Abril/2020', 'Maio/2020', 'junho/2020', 'julho/2020', 'Agosto/2020',
                    'Setembro/2020', 'Outubro/2020', 'Novembro/2020', 'Dezembro/2020',
                    'Janeiro/2021', 'fereiro/2021', 'Março/2021', 'Abril/2021', 'Maio/2021',
                    'junho/2021', 'julho/2021', 'Agosto/2021', 'Setembro/2021',
                    'Outubro/2021', 'Dezembro/2021', 'Novembro/2021', 'fereiro/2022',
                    'Março/2022', 'Abril/2022', 'Maio/2022', 'junho/2022', 'julho/2022',
                    'Agosto/2022', 'Setembro/2022', 'Outubro/2022', 'Novembro/2022',
                    'Dezembro/2022', 'Janeiro/2023', 'fereiro/2023', 'Março/2023',
                    'Abril/2023', 'Maio/2023', 'junho/2023', 'julho/2023', 'Agosto/2023',
                    'Setembro/2023', 'Outubro/2023']
                marks = {i: option for i, option in enumerat
e(slider_options)}

                app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SOLAR],suppress_callback_exceptions=True)


                app.layout =html.Div( children=[
                    dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col([dbc.Card([
                            html.H3('Selecione o período'),
                            dcc.Dropdown(options=marks
                                ,id='slider',
                                ),

                            html.H3('Seleione a corretora'),
                            dcc.Checklist(arquivo_final['Corretora'].value_counts().index,id='corretora'),

                            html.H3('Seleione o estado'),

                            dcc.Checklist(arquivo_final['UF'].value_counts().index,id='estado'),

                            html.H3('Seleione o escritorio'),
                            dcc.Checklist(arquivo_final['Escritorio'].value_counts().index,id='Escritorio')


                @app.callback(
                    Output('pl_total_barra','figure'),

                    [Input('corretora','value'),
                    Input('estado','value'),
                    Input('Escritorio','value'),
                    Input('slider','value')]
                )
                def update_fig(broker,city,office,selected_option):
                    if not broker or not city or not office or not selected_option:
                        return go.Figure()

                    filtro_corretora = arquivo_final[arquivo_final['Corretora'].isin(broker)]
                    filtro_estado = filtro_corretora[filtro_corretora['UF'].isin(city)]
                    filtro_office = filtro_estado[filtro_estado['Escritorio'].isin(office)]



                    if selected_option in marks:
                        selected_colum = marks[selected_option]
                        if selected_colum in filtro_office.columns:
                            value_to_show = filtro_office[selected_colum].sum()


                    fig_pl_total = go.Figure()
                    fig_pl_total.add_trace(go.Indicator(
                        value=value_to_show
                    ))



                    return fig_pl_total

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    app.run_server(debug=True)`


                `
                `
```

Instead of summing the column and showing the value, I'm getting this error:

UnboundLocalError: cannot access the local variable 'value_to_show' where it is not associated with a value.

Traceback (most recent call last):
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'value_to_show' where it is not associated with a value.